# Highlight for two strings simultaneously in vi or less editor?

Tags: centos, vim, vi

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41901319/how-to-search-for-multiple-strings-in-a-log-file-using-less-command-in-unix

I found this.

```
awk '/pattern1/ && /pattern2/ && /pattern3/' file.log | less
```

I tried this command, but it's not my expected output.

I want to highlight multiple search strings simultaneously in vi/less editor or using any other things like awk etc.

I just want to highlight both, nothing else is required.

```
/.*(string1.*string2|string2.*string1).*
```

I tried this but it was highlighting the entire paragraph instead of just two stuffs.

I tried https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/124222-commang-search-two-strings-vi.html

this and it was showing this.

```
/StringOne\|StringTwo
```

But it resulted into pattern not found as expected.

I tried

```
egrep "one|two" file
```

It is nice but I can't do next, previous as it's not an editor. So, there's that caveat.

One thing that I found in the past was https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Highlight_multiple_words
but due to lack of documentation to install and use it, I've not yet started. And I am unsure if this will work in linux centos 7 or not.

I'm on vim 7.4

Answer (score 1):

To search for either `foo` or `bar`, it's

```
/foo|bar
```

in `less` where `less` regexps extend POSIX extended (egrep-like) regexps where `|` is an alternation operator.

And:

```
/foo\|bar
```

Or `/vfoo|bar` in `vim` where `vim` regexps extend the `vi` regexps which themselves extend POSIX basic regexps where `|` alone matches a literal `|`.

`awk '/foo/ && /bar/'` would match on lines that contain *both* `foo` and `bar`. Searching a `foo` provided it's found on a line also containing `bar` or a `bar` provided it's found on a line also containing `foo` could be done in `vim` using its look-around regexp operators:

```
 /\vfoo(.*bar)@=|(bar.*)@<=foo|bar(.*foo)@=|(foo.*)@<=bar
```

That is `\v` for *very-magic* where many more operators are recognised without the need for a leading `\`, and then match either:

- `foo` provided it's followed by any amount of characters and `bar` using the `@=` look-ahead operator.
- `foo` provided it's preceded by `bar` followed by any amount of characters using the `@<=` look-behind operator.
- `bar` provided it's followed by any amount of characters and `foo`
- `bar` provided it's preceded by `foo` followed by any amount of characters

To turn on highlighting of search matches in `vim`:

```
:set hls
```

If you just want to *highlight* without searching, you can use syntax highlighting in `vim`. For instance:

```
:syn match Search "foo"
:syn match Error "bar"
```

Would highlight occurrences of `foo` the same way as search results and `bar` as errors.

Comment: I'm unable to process that what I was stuck for so long was this simple /foo|bar

Answer (score 0):

One way to highlight multiple words is to use your own colouring function such as :

```
hilite () 
{ 
    sed "/$1/s/$1/\x1b[01;31m&\x1b[0m/g"
}
```

Then you can pipe in your text file and indicate the words to be highlighted - one at a time:

```
$ cat infile | hilite word1 | hilite word2 | hilite word3
```

To view the highlighted text in less, use -R option:

```
$ cat infile | hilite word1 | hilite word2 | hilite word3 | less -R
```

Comment: It's far simpler to use `grep`: `grep -e word1 -e word2 -e word3 ...`

Comment: Sometimes you need the full text with words highlighted. grep  only show the lines with matched patterns.

Comment: (add a `-e ^ for that`)